# Multi inheritance and design pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

In the [facebook-python-business-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk) library, I've seen something that I thought it was bad practice :

[AdAccountUserMixin](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/master/facebook_business/adobjects/helpers/adaccountusermixin.py)'s get_pages() method uses self.iterate_edge() which is neither a method of this class nor a parent's.

[AbstractCrudObject](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/15c8b3e453f6115d029a2b5270c710d04e1c1c81/facebook_business/adobjects/abstractcrudobject.py) implements this method.

And then, [AdAccountUser](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/a8fc2dd815f4228ed6013d2c66d13ddae856b9fc/facebook_business/adobjects/adaccountuser.py) inherits from these two classes. That's why an object of AdAccountUser can use the method get_pages().

Minimal example :

```
class AbstractBar:
   def bar(self, x):
       return x

class Foo:
   def foo(self, x):
       return self.bar(x)

class Test(Foo, AbstractBar):
   def test(self, x):
       return self.foo(x)


t = Test()

t.test(5) # returns 5
```

Is this a design pattern, something that you see everyday or just a bad practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite ordinary [mixin class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) stuff. A mixin class is a class that is explicitely designed to complement a given base class or interface (it explicitely relies on the class it's "mixed-in" with to implement a given interface). This is quite useful when you want to factor out some common behaviour from a bunch of classes that implement the same interface without having a common ancestor.

Comment: Shouldn't the Mixin class Foo have an "abstract" method bar() that raises a NotImplementedError or something like this ? Or is this just not pythonic or something that you see only for an abstract class ?

Comment: If you defined this "abstract" method in the mixin class, you couldn't use cooperative `super` calls anymore. The mixin's doc is supposed to clearly document which interface it's "host" class is supposed to implement, and that's about it. Given Python's highly dynamic nature, those kind of checks are mostly useless anyway (the "bar" method could as well be added as a moneypatch in a different part of the code - brittlle, hardly maintainable and definitly not a good practice but sometimes a Q&D fix is better than a broken app, at least until you can release a proper clean fix).